# Algoritmo Suma de cuadrados Java ciclos

Tags: java

Diseñe un programa que permita calcular la suma de los cuadradados de una serie de numeros de multiplos de 3; la cual inicia en 3 y termina en N.
Por ejemplo:
Si el usuario ingresa el numero de 10, el programa debe mostar la suma de los cuadrados del 3 al 9 (3+6+9), siendo el resultado 126

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Esto no es el rinconDelVago. Peléate con el código y cuando tengas un problema de codigo que no sepas resolver, vuelve aqui.

Comment: @ferter3006, la referencia al sitio **rinconDelVago**, se puede entender tranquilamente como un insulto, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, y hagas otro más "acogedor", ya que se trata de un usuario nuevo, gracias!.

Answer (score -2):

Aquí está el código, te recomendaría que te peleases tú con el código, ya que es la única manera de la que se aprende, pero bueno, allá tu...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Introduzca N -> " );
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int suma = 0;
    
    if(num < 3){
        System.out.println("Introduzca un número mayor que 3");
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i = i + 3){
            suma = suma + (i*i);
        }
        System.out.println("El resultado es " + suma);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo